# How can I retrieve step data from a Wear OS device for my Android health app?

Tags: android, flutter, wear-os

I have develop an android based health application. I want to take data like users steps from a Wear OS device and display it in my application. How exactly do I achieve this.

I have read the documentation on https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer but still could not understand what I should do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can use health services client to achieve that. i use it with kotlin, but it should be the same probably. 
you can find example code here: https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/health-services/PassiveData